# How to ignore Authorization header for anonymous requests?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I am trying to disable security for the URLs with the header `abcd` and value `myabcdValue`.

It works fine. But when I pass `Authorization` header it is expecting the valid token.

I am using Spring Boot 2.7.7.

How can we ignore `Authorization` Header for anonymous access?

```java
public SecurityFilterChain resourceServerSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) {
     http
         //.antMatcher("/**/api/**")
         .csrf().disable()
         .authorizeRequests()
              .requestMatchers(new RequestHeaderRequestMatcher("abcd", "myabcdValue")).permitAll()
              .and()
          .authorizeRequests()
              .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
              .antMatchers("/csrf").permitAll()
              .antMatchers("/api/**").permitAll()
              .antMatchers("/swagger-ui/**", "/swagger-resources/**", "/webjars/**", "/v2/api-docs",
                  "/v3/api-docs").permitAll()
              .requestMatchers(EndpointRequest.to("info", "health")).permitAll() // actuator
              .anyRequest().authenticated()
              .and()
          .sessionManagement()
              .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
              .and()
          .oauth2ResourceServer()
              .accessDeniedHandler(exceptionHandler)
              .authenticationEntryPoint(exceptionHandler)
              .jwt()
              .decoder(jwtDecoder)
              .jwtAuthenticationConverter(new JwtRolesConverter());

          return http.build();
}
```

Comment: You could also write a `RequestHeaderRequestMatcher` for that header.

Comment: However, this line `requestMatchers(new RequestHeaderRequestMatcher("abcd", "myabcdValue")).permitAll()` will open all endpoints, if you know the header and value. That is a security issue.